# Why does the amount of RUs change my CosmosDB result set sizes?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-cosmosdb

This one has me completely baffled.

**Context:** I am running a stored proc on CosmosDB which returns result sets along with continuation tokens should there be multiple "pages" of data (of which there will always be at least a few). There are a total of 65,000 records in my collection. For the last "page", the continuation token should (and does) return as NULL from CosmosDB, indicating that the entirety of my collection has been returned.

**My problem:** 
When I set my CosmosDB collection's RUs to the minimum (400), the data sets come through fine, along with their continuation tokens for the next page, and all is well with the world. As soon as I bump up my RUs (for faster query execution), the continuation tokens come through fine for the first few "pages" but then suddenly returns as NULL about half-way through the entire data set.

**Here is my stored proc:**

```
function count(continuationToken) {
var filterQuery = 'select c.id from c where c.Type = 0';
var collection = getContext().getCollection();
var maxResult = 900000;
var result = [];
tryQuery(continuationToken);

function tryQuery(nextContinuationToken) {
    var responseOptions = { continuation: nextContinuationToken, pageSize: maxResult };
    if (result.length >= maxResult || !query(responseOptions)) {
        setBody(nextContinuationToken);
    }
}
function query(responseOptions) {
    return collection.queryDocuments(collection.getSelfLink(), filterQuery, responseOptions, onReadDocuments);
}
function onReadDocuments(err, docFeed, responseOptions) {
    if (err) {
        throw 'Error while reading document: ' + err;
    }
    result.push(docFeed);
    if (responseOptions.continuation) {
        tryQuery(responseOptions.continuation);
    } else {
        setBody(null);
    }
}
function setBody(continuationToken) {
    var body = { records: result, continuationToken: continuationToken };        
    getContext().getResponse().setBody(body);
}
}
```

Does anybody have any ideas as to what might be going wrong here? It doesn't make sense to me that RUs should have an impact on the amount of data returned from a CosmosDB collection.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: can you please email askcosmosdb@microsoft.com to help us reproduce this? Some sample documents will help.

Comment: To be clear, this is not expected. Also, you may know this, but you should use SQL query vs. stored procedure for read operations like COUNT - they're more efficient and lesser code